# Load one module from Angular Library Instead of loading the whole library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have an angular library that has been generated with the following command:

```
ng generate library cac-models
```

In this library, I have two modules named Admin and Client Module.When I'd like to use Admin module I have to load it like the following command  and then import it:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminModule } from 'cac-models';  //=> this line

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports:
    [
      BrowserModule,
      AdminModule,
      AppRoutingModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This way, Angular loads the whole library (both admin and client module), because I import AdminModule from cac-models.

I'd like to load only the Admin Module. like below:

```
 import { AdminModule } from 'cac-models/lib/admin/admin.module'; // I get error
```

In this way, I get the following error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cac-models/lib/admin/admin.module'

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, you have the following structure in the projects folder :

```
-projects
---------cac-models
-------------------src
----------------------lib
-------------------------Admin(module)
--------------------------------------admin-component-one
--------------------------------------admin-component-two
--------------------------------------admin-component-three
-------------------------Client(module)
---------------------------------------client-component-one
---------------------------------------client-component-two
---------------------------------------client-component-three
----------------------public-api.ts
```

AdminModule :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations:
    [
      AdminComponentOneComponent,
      AdminComponentTwoComponent,
      AdminComponentThreeComponent
    ],
  imports:
    [
      CommonModule
    ],
  exports:
    [
      AdminComponentOneComponent,
      AdminComponentTwoComponent,
      AdminComponentThreeComponent
    ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

ClientModule :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations:
    [
      ClientComponentOneComponent,
      ClientComponentTwoComponent,
      ClientComponentThreeComponent
    ],
  imports:
    [
      CommonModule
    ],
  exports:
    [
      ClientComponentOneComponent,
      ClientComponentTwoComponent,
      ClientComponentThreeComponent
    ]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

your `public-api` should be like the following:

```
export * from './lib/admin/admin.module';
export * from './lib/client/client.module';
```

then , build the `cac-models` library with the following command :

```
ng build cac-models
```

wherever you want to use only `AdminModule`, you have to import it like the following :

```
import { AdminModule } from 'cac-models';
```

maybe you ask your self, here Angular loads the whole library , the answer is : no , here Angular loads only AdminModule of cac-models instead the whole library .

for test:

import AdminModule in the AppModule  then install [Augury extension](https://augury.rangle.io/) to see the result
(**here you will see that angualr loads only AdminModule(along with 3 exported components) insted of the whole library**)

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing AdminModule specifically only that will be a part of the final build and all the dead code will be removed. This happens as a part of tree shaking which you read about here https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: @Barkha- Thanks, Your explanation is awesome.
In development mode angular loads everything from our custom library but in production mode Angular loads only Whatever is needed.